# Not able to run ajax code on chrome ,IE or firefox

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-chrome

Is there any error in the code, the code is copied from w3schools for practice. when I click me pen drive button I am not redirected to the page mobile.txt
 has the problem?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<div id="demo">
<h1>The XMLHttpRequest Object</h1>
<button type="button" onclick="loadDoc()">pendrive</button>

</div>

<script>
function loadDoc() {
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =
  this.responseText;
  }
 };
xhttp.open("GET", "mobile.txt", true);
xhttp.send();
}

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: First - What error are you getting in your browser console. ? And second AJAX call is used to load data onto the page and not redirect you to another  page, if you wish to do that you can use `window.location.href = "http://someurl.com"`

Answer (score 0):

Buddy, it is because your code is not able to locate the "mobile.txt" file.

Check the browser console for any errors, you will see 404 (File not found) Error in it.

What that code does is, to get that particular file and show it in your UI.

Answer (score 0):

It is a little surprising.

Please make sure you have the 'mobile.txt' in the same directory with the html document. If you have, try updating your browser. The general 'new XMLHttpRequest()' Method may not be compatible with the version of your browser

Apart from that, I assure you everything in your code is perfect.